# Make counter not be less than zero in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { value: 5 };

  increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that whenever I click the Decrement button, the value will not be less than 0. The value's minimum will always be zero and not -1, -2 ,-3 ,-4 ...

Comment: Before you dive into React I would go back to basics on variables and conditionals. Hint: if (condition) { // do something } else { // do something else }

Comment: Thank you for the tip, just wanted to dip my foot in React if I can handle it. But yeah, I will go back to basics.

Answer (score 4):

Just set a minimum value in your decrementing code:

```
decrement = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    value: Math.max(prevState.value - 1, 0)
  }));
};
```

Comment: Nice intuitive answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, It works but I don't understand the logic behind this. if possible, can you explain how it works?

EDIT: Okay , after reading the documentation, I understand now. Thank you again, no reply needed.

Comment: `Math.max` is a function that takes two number values and returns the bigger one. In this case, all numbers are being compared to zero. So if `prevState - 1` is less than zero, `Marth.max` will return zero instead. If you feel like you need to review the basics of javascript, I would recommend this book: https://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 0):

That's how number input works. To simplify the code you could try to use [validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) state (if your target browsers support it)

```
onChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.badInput) {
        this.setState(Number(e.target.value))
    }
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5k250m87)

Answer (score 0):

you can test it

```
 const onPressDecrement = () => setCount((prevCount) => (Math.max(prevCount - 1,1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**On Way Use Conditional (ternary) operator  in decrement  Function**

```
     decrement = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          value: prevState.value ? prevState.value -1 : 0
        }));
      };
```